# Clip type for in-system programming (SOIC8 vs DIP8)

Tags: spi, isp, icsp, soic

**Updated:**

What clip can I use to connect to this [[specsheet](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q64fv%20revq%2006142016.pdf)] SPI flash chip in a DIP8 package?

[image]

**note:** this picture is of a motherboard that belongs to someone else, but mine has the same manufacturer, model-family, and Winbond 25Q64FVAIG. Only the third line (date code?) is different. The surrounding circuitry appears identical.

---

**Original post:**

I'm under the impression I can't use a SOIC8 clip to connect to a DIP8 package.

I'm seeing a large number of clips labelled both SOIC8 and DIP8 ([1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N5CN3P5), [2](https://abra-electronics.com/test-equipment-tools/test-clips-leads-banana-posts/generic-low-cost/itc-8a-programmer-ic-testing-clip-8-pin-sop-soic-dip.html)) - one with a description saying *"clip onto any 8 pin SOP, SOIC or DIP package."*

What am I missing?

Comment: Assuming the IC is programmable, if the board has no connector for ISP it might still be impossible to program it as some lines cannot be put into the proper state for programming even if you find a matching clip. E.g. if it was never intended to be prgrammed in-system the programming data line might be driven by another IC or used as output etc. What is the IC and the surrounding circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the pin pitch is different so you'd need a dedicated DIP clip or a dedicated SOIC clip. I think the description for that product may be misleading.

EDIT: The chip is socketed so you can carefully pry it up and program it outside of the circuit, like on a breadboard. This is probably what's best unless there's a dedicated header on the board for in-circuit programming. Taking it out of the circuit removes ambiguity as you can control what it's connected to. You won't need a test clip anymore either.

Comment: The pitch ratio between the two is 1:2. So I guess one can go to another leaving each second pin unconnected

Comment: I see what you mean, so in theory you'd need to buy a SOIC-16 test clip to use it on a DIP-8 package. Maybe that could work!

Comment: The reliability of those clips was often questionable on DIP packages, I can't imagine trying to make them stay put on surface-mount parts. Much better to add a header beside it for programming needs.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to flash a ROM on a desktop motherboard, so adding a header is not an option. I've clarified the question a little.

Comment: @Rob: Good luck trying to flash a ROM! Do you know what ROM means?

Comment: yes, but ROM doesn't mean EEPROM.